# How can I get events from a generic USB HID device in Psychtoolbox-3?

Tags: matlab, usb, hid, psychtoolbox

I have a Griffin Technology 'PowerMate' USB knob.  It's apparently HID compliant, and I'm able to detect it with the following bit of code:

```
 LoadPsychHID;
devs = PsychHID('Devices');
for i = 1:length(devs)
    index = devs(i).index;
    if strfind(devs(i).product, 'PowerMate')
        break
    end
end
```

The device index is `1`.

I then try to start an event queue for the device:

```
KbQueueCreate(index);
PsychHID('KbQueueStart', index);
```

No errors so far, so I check it with `CharAvail`

```
[avail, numChars] = CharAvail

avail =

     0


numChars =

     0
```

Furthermore, running `[have_events, a, b, c, d] = KbQueueCheck(index);` returns a boolean `True` for the variable `have_events` and empty matrices for variables `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`.

What am I doing wrong?  Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**  For what it's worth, I don't need very accurate timing here, so if there's a way to get this to work in plain-old Matlab, that's also fine.  No need to use Psychtoolbox if it's not strictly necessary!

Thanks!

Comment: Note that your code does not work in every case. If `length(devs)` is equal to 1, your value `index` will be 1 no matter what `strfind(devs(i).product, 'PowerMate')` returns.

Comment: @H.Muster Good catch!  This *shouldn't* be a problem since I have several devices that are returned by `PsychHID('Devices')`, but I'll correct this just to avoid any future headaches.  Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Did you already read this (short) discussion concerning the PowerMate? http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/psychtoolbox/message/6914

Comment: @H.Muster,  I did.  This is why I'm confused about my CharAvail output...  Did I miss something?

Comment: Just some random questions: (1) Do you run matlab with the `-nojvm` option? (2) Did you try KBCheck?